# How to disable odometry from ROSAria

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-odometry, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a way to disable wheel odometry (at least the TF) that is published by ROSAria? I want to use odometry from another source like visual odometry. This is how my TF [frames](https://imgur.com/a/lLVl6Oy) look like atm. I have two separate trees because ROSAria still publishes `odom` to `base_link`.

I use Ubuntu 14.04. with ROS Kinetic.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299141/how-to-disable-odometry-from-rosaria/) by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[It would appear not](https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria/blob/aa8d5f7faf4b2bc57bea2c597efee1b9a79953ea/RosAria.cpp#L567). If you'd like that feature, it seems like a pretty straightforward change for you to contribute.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1